# QVariant from QList<QList<MyClass>>

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qvariant

I want to save a `QList<QList<MyClass>>` as QVariant but I alway get the error `QVariant::save: unable to save type 'QList<QList<MyClass*> >' (type id: 1042)`. I've implemente the streaming operator for MyClass and it works fine.

```
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& out, const MyClass& item)
{   
    //Properties to write
    return out;
}

QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& in, MyClass& item)
{   
    //Properties to read
    return in;
}
```

I also registered the types

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass*)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<MyClass*>)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<QList<MyClass*>>)
```

and

```
qRegisterMetaType<QList<MyClass*>>("QList<MyClass*>");
qRegisterMetaType<QList<QList<MyClass*>>>("QList<QList<MyClass*>>");
qRegisterMetaType<MyClass*>("MyClass*");
```

If I only stream one MyClass Object everything is fine. I can save it as QVariant, stream it and convert it back to MyClass. I thought I don't have to implement a operator for `QList<MyClass>` or `QList<QList<MyClass>>` because streaming a Template Class in a QList is already implemented by Qt. So whats the matter?

Comment: MyClass inherits from QObject or from some kind of Qt?

Comment: A `MyClass*` and a `MyClass` are not the same thing.  Are you sure you want to store a `MyClass*` in your list of lists?

Comment: I pass the MyClass pointer to the streaming operator and only stream things like QString, QPointF, etc.. So I don't stream the pointer itself just copy the properties and set them to a new created pointer object.

@eyllanesc
Yep, it inherites from QObject. And as I said for single objects its no problem but for the Objects in a QList or QList of QLists.

Comment: @NathanOliver - internally QList will use pointers nonetheless. Which is how it even works for QObject which is not copyable.